# Resistivity and resistance. Permittivity and?

Tags: capacitance, theory

We know that resistance is dependent on both the materials resistivity and the geometry of the material. For a cylindrical or rectangular material the resistance is:

$$R=\rho*\frac{l}{A}$$

where l is the length and A the cross-sectional area.

In the same manner I understand that permittivity is a measure of how an electric field affects, and is affected by, a dielectric medium. When I look at capacitance I can see that it is dependent on the permittivity and the geometry. An example is the parallel plate capacitor's capacitance:

$$C=\epsilon\frac{A}{d}$$

where A is the area of the plates/dielectric and d the distance between the conductive plates.

Is capacitance the same as "permittance"? If not, what is the geometry dependent permittivity?

Comment: **Permittance** was a word used by Heaviside for what we now call *susceptance* which is the imaginary part of *admittance* (the real part being *conductance*), which in turn is the inverse of *impedance*.   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oliver_Heaviside

Comment: @SpehroPefhany: It would make more sense to still use this word as far as I understand. Thanks for letting me know it was actually a word named permittance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the unit analysis: Resistivity is measured in Ω-m. When you mutliply by length (m) and divide by area (m<sup>2</sup>), you're left with just Ω.

Permittivity is measured in Farads/m. When you multiply by area (m<sup>2</sup>) and divide by spacing (m), you're left with just Farads, or capacitance.